# Configure docker network in Azure VM to be accessible from other VMs

Tags: networking, azure, docker, virtual-machines

I have a problem solving some connectivity issues in my Azure Setup. Lets start with my use-case:

"I want to be able to have two VMs in Azure in the same Subnet (10.240.0.0/16) with e.g. IPs 10.240.0.4 and 10.240.0.5. The VM with IP 10.240.0.4 has docker EE installed and hosts 5 docker containers which are also in the same subnet. E.g the first container has the IP 10.240.120.1. I want to communicate now from the container at 10.240.120.1 with the VM at 10.240.0.5"

I have exactly this setup on-premise already. But I struggle doing it in Azure.

What did I got so far: Right now, I can communicate from my container to the host where it is running on and vice versa (e.g. ping 10.240.0.4 works from the container and ping 10.240.120.1 works from the VM). I can ping between both VMs (e.g. ping 10.240.0.4 works from 10.240.0.5 and ping 10.240.0.4 works from 10.240.0.5). But I can not ping the container at 10.240.120.1 from 10.240.0.5.

I tried different network drivers like transparent, l2bridge and l2tunnel without success.

On-premises I use the "transparent" network driver. However, looking at the documentation at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/virtualization/windowscontainers/container-networking/network-drivers-topologies I got the info that that will not work in Azure

> Due to the following requirement, connecting your container hosts
>   over a transparent network is not supported on Azure VMs. Requires:
>   When this mode is used in a virtualization scenario (container host is
>   a VM) MAC address spoofing is required.

Right now I am stuck with the following l2bridge network:

```
[
{
    "Name": "l2bridge_for_gsim_global",
    "Id": "c5eabf411db8a856b9c0c9d6bc1e3bf09455065a12a981cff067ff9fe8d47c66",
    "Created": "2020-02-24T08:40:50.6804326Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "l2bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "windows",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "10.240.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "10.240.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "3ed2b2bbcf6fa9de66460f94078a59669effe3bf25530b1bea5970844df9620f": {
            "Name": "DEFAULT-GSim-Global-1",
            "EndpointID": "4e5e6801484dec6c4b7a5a56846924196a1ef77a3e8bea8ebc6d8c39d02910b8",
            "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:e7:f8:11",
            "IPv4Address": "10.240.120.1/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "4a17a5bd8c45e73054c79b3fd199bb43d93e0cb2084bf94c74d656d5550d357d": {
            "Name": "DEFAULT-GSIMSQL-1",
            "EndpointID": "5146fa456e0c3c424322a6451c7a55d10b545ac08110e084359b4e1b1c67c9be",
            "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:e7:fc:5c",
            "IPv4Address": "10.240.100.1/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "b11b11a1c01e92a0731691f8608a04eef325cbbc426ca6ac2cca719080f68fa2": {
            "Name": "DEFAULT-GCORESQL-1",
            "EndpointID": "a74c1af87a7e51a79cb455afa84d8b0c3519588e476b5c749a0fb48f79e09e6b",
            "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:e7:f9:44",
            "IPv4Address": "10.240.140.1/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "bd773562d19c3bc925eb944639ad253b24d8330f0fbaba5aebbd9e008c9bdc56": {
            "Name": "DEFAULT-GCORE-1",
            "EndpointID": "f3af1fb7d50b28f0cfd415a13052faaabdad3cd539c79583ba646da455a20cf3",
            "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:e7:fd:ce",
            "IPv4Address": "10.240.160.1/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.windowsshim.enable_outboundnat": "true",
        "com.docker.network.windowsshim.hnsid": "FE7C256E-71EF-468F-9305-E14C8E0D5F3D",
        "com.docker.network.windowsshim.networkname": "l2bridge_for_gsim_global"
    },
    "Labels": {}
}
]
```

I tried to analyze the issue with wireshark. I can clearly see that when I try to ping 10.240.0.5 from the docker container, on my host the is an ARP-Request and ICMP packages created. However, they never reach the VM at 10.240.0.5 (checked with Wireshark aswell. Therefore I suspect that they are discarded/blocked somewhere inbetween?

[Wireshark from Host-VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTVof.png)

Would be cool if there is a way to monitor the packets going through my VNET as I can do it with a Router/Firewall on-premises, to check if they get dropped by the VM-Host somewhere else.

Anyway, does anyone have an idea how I can further debug this or how to properly configure the docker network to fullfill my above use-case? If any more information is needed, I will gladfully prepare it.

Thanks in advance,

Mangosniper

PS: Some more infos about why I am using VMs with Docker EE instead of AKS or ACI for example. I am using Windows Docker containers and AKS does not support a custom VNET with windows containers (So a VNET where I can change some settings afterwards). Therefore it was not an option. ACI does not support internal IPs for the Containers it runs, therefore every container would get a public IP. That does also not fit my use-case. Therefore I ended up with an Azure VM with Windows Server 2019 with Docker EE.

Comment: where did you get the info that AKS does not support custom Vnets with windows containers? It does.

Comment: @SamCogan, I actually just did some research about where I found that info but I can not find it anymore. Therefore I have to assume I got it wrong :O

Comment: You can definitely do it with AKS nodes. There is a limitation on ACI windows containers that can't be vNet attached, but not AKS

Comment: I was going to add an answer to use L2Tunnel, but I missed that you did try that.

Comment: You can use a custom VNet with AKS and Windows containers. All you have to do is to create the vNet first on the same RG and region, then on the wizard you can select that custom vNet. If you are using Azure PowerShell for that, you can leverage part of the script I have here: https://github.com/microsoft/ITOpsTalk/blob/main/gMSAAKSTrial/DeployAKS.ps1